# Feature scaling a linear regression model and how it affects the output

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have input data that looks like:

```
col1            col2        col3  col4  col5  col 6
-0.1144887   -0.1717161    3847  3350  2823  2243
 0.3534122   0.53008300    4230  3520  2421  3771
 ...
```

So columns 1 and 2 range from -1 to 1, and columns 3-6 range from 2000-5000

The output data ranges from 5.0 to 10.0. I expect to predict a single real-valued output for each input vector and am using a linear regression dense neural network with an 'mse' loss function.

I'm thinking I should scale columns 3-6 to between 0 and 1 and leave columns 1 and 2 as is. Is that correct or should I also scale columns 1 and 2 to be between 0 and 1? If I scale the input, does that affect my predicted output value or does it only speed up the learning? Is there any need to scale the output?

Comment: From what I've read, I should scale each input feature column independently to the same range, and there is no need to scale the output. I have tried that but unfortunately my model is producing NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

You should scale all the features in the same range. The standard way is to center to the mean value and scale using the variance:

1) compute the mean value and the variance of the features using the training set (e.g. col1_av=average(col1_train), col2_av=average(col2_train),...)

2) from each feature subtract the corresponding mean value and scale wrt the variance(e.g. [x1=-0.1144887,x2=0.3534122,...]-> (x1-col1_av)/col1_var). The sample in the test set must be scaled using the value estimated on the training set.

Having features so different in magnitude will affect also the output and not only the learning process since feature with larger magnitude will weight more in the model.

In general there is no need to scale the output.

An interesting read: https://medium.com/greyatom/why-how-and-when-to-scale-your-features-4b30ab09db5e

Comment: Is this operation the same as sklearn.preprocessing Standard Scaler? Right now I'm using the MinMax scalar and the scaled data winds up with NaNs in it.

Comment: @julieb I gave a look to the function and it seems that is the same. The MinMax scalar seems to be an alternative to the zero centering that I have suggested. There could be several reasons why you get the NaNs. Two possibilities are 1) there are features that have constant values for all the samples 2) there are NaNs in your data.